# Send as Distribution Groups in Exchange

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

Can you only configure Send As permissions on Mail Universal Security groups?

Or are you also able to set Send As permissions on Mail Universal Distribution Groups?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to Send As the email address of the group? Or are you trying to put people in to a group, and use that group to assign Send As permissions to another mailbox?

Comment: Send As the email address of the group

Answer (score 1):

You can send as either a Mail Distribution Group or a Mail Security Group. However, the commands to give these permissions are different.

For a Mail Distribution Group:

```
Add-RecipientPermission <group> -AccessRights sendas -Trustee <user>
```

For a Mail Security Group:

```
Add-ADPermission <group> -ExtendedRights "send-as" -user <user>
```

Comment: I think this is being made way more complex that it needs to be - my question was - Does your Distribution Group have to be a Mail Enabled Security Group (and NOT a normal Disitribution Group) in order to assign Send As rights to a user.

Comment: Or can you assign a Distribution Group (which is not a Security group) and give Send As Permissions to a user

Comment: Even if my initial revision had a poorly worded first sentence, the fact that I showed how to assign permissions so a user can send as a group should have given it away: both types support the ability for users to send-as that group.

Comment: Well Add-RecipientPermission applies only to Exchange Online

Comment: Actually Add-RecipientPermission applies to OnPrem as well.